# foreign key conflict Unable to insert data

Tags: sql, asp-classic, foreign-keys

I have two tables having following fields:

Table 1 :

**Student Master**

Fields :

```
stu_id(primary key)
name
class
doc upload
sub_id(foreign_key)
```

Table 2:

**Subject**

Fields :

```
sub_id(primary key)
subject name
```

But when I insert the entries in the form it gives the following error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__student_m__sub_i__0C85DE4D". The conflict occurred in database "test2", table "dbo.subject", column 'sub_id'**

Kindly help where am I wrong??

Comment: Did you try to add subid to student master that doesn't exists on subjects?

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to insert a value in `Student Master`'s sub_id which not exists int the `Subject` table (there is no reference in the `Subject` table)

If those are the first records, then make sure, that you first insert the `Subject` then the `Student Master`

Comment: But I have a dropdown as Subject who's value that is sub_id I get from the subject table

Comment: Then you should test your insert, because the error means what I and the others described. May the problem is in your code.

Comment: I already checked the sub_id's which are being inserted into student_master already exist in subject table.I know the basic that foreign key must exist in the table of which it is a primary key.

Comment: In this case my best advice is to use SQL Profiler and you will see the statement what your application created, and then the problem immedietly will be visible for sure!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are inserting record in the `Student Master` table which `sub_id` is not present on the table `subject`. Remember that you have specified `sub_id` of `Student Master` table as the foreign key from `subject` table. It also means the `Student Master` table is dependent on `subject` table. This breaks referential integrity.

Comment: What should I do to rectify it??

Comment: @Coder1010 the best way is to insert first all the needed records (*that you think it may*) on the subject table and later on you can use the `ID`s when you insert on the `student master` table

Comment: I already checked the sub_id's which are being inserted into student_master already exist in subject table.I know the basic that foreign key must exist in the table of which it is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

> **The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.**

Because it is a foreign key constraint which tells you that the value you are trying to insert in the table which is not there in a referenced table.

So you first have to make sure while inserting into `Student` table that `sub_id` is available in the `subject` table.

EDIT:

To Rectify it try this command in Sql server management studio:

```
sp_help 'dbo.subject'
```

Comment: But my subject is a dropdown which has the values bound from the subject table,means all the values exist in the subject table.Then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the master record first and then the child record.
first insert the record in Student Master table and then try inserting in Subject table.
will be help you better if you send me your insert statement.